# Ubuntu not booting from USB Stick

Tags: 14.04, boot, freeze

Everything works perfectly...but when I try to boot Ubuntu from my USB..a black screen appears and stays there forever. I left like that for a day...still it remained the same. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The .iso file may not have burned properly to the drive. You can try to fromat the drive and create the starup disk again and reboot.

Comment: I did that 2 or 3 times... using PenDriveLinux :)

Comment: Then download the iso file again and try

Comment: Tried...still...doesn't work..!

Comment: try  Unetbootin.

Answer (score 0):

make sure whether your downloaded iso is complete by using MD5SUM at
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

if SUM doesn't match:
then add the torrent of corresponding ubuntu version to the location of your iso on your harddisk, then it completes the missing parts and your iso and gets downloaded completely.

if SUM matches:
use rufus from windows computer to make bootable usb with options
1)uefi or mbr patition scheme
2)fat32

then open bios
1)secure boot off
2)fast boot off

press f2 while reboot and select usb   :)